# boost::multi_array resize exception?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I'm trying to figure out if the boost::multi_array constructor or resize method can throw a bad_alloc exception (or some other exception indicating the allocation or resize failed).  I can't find this information in the documentation anywhere.

*Clarification (added from comment):*

This is a scientific algorithm that can fall back to a less memory intensive (slower) method if the allocation fails.  Basically there are two dynamically allocated 3-dimensional arrays to hold "distances" (correlation) between all pairs of genes in a query and all genes in a cross-validation set for each of a large number of datasets. The slower method recalculates each distance on the fly as it is needed. This is for a C++ version of an existing Java implementation, which implemented both methods and would fall back on an out of memory exception. I don't really expect to run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1st:* (answering the real question): As it uses dynamically allocated memory, yes, it can throw `std::bad_alloc` (I have never seen boost translation `std::bad_alloc` exceptions; it would be crazy to do so).

*2nd:* (comment on your clarification): You do need the information of available physical memory to optimize the performance of your algorithm at run-time.  However, you cannot rely on `std::bad_alloc` to determine how much memory you have available, as modern operating systems use such a thing as *overcommit*, meaning: they (almost) never return a failed allocation attempt, but instead just give you some "memory", which will only fail to jump into existence when you actually try to access it.

In Java this may work as the VM is doing many things for you: it tries to allocate some continuous memory chunks, and does so with respect to the available physical memory, and the available *unused* physical memory to decide whether it should stress the GC more or just allocate a larger junk.  Also, for performance reason you need to take into account that virtual memory and physical memory are quite different concepts.

If you *need* to performance-optimize you algorithms for such cases (which may well be necessary, depending on your area of work), you need to inspect your platform-specific functions which can tell you how "the real world" looks like.

Comment: see my comment above, the algorithm, as implemented by the original researcher in Java, supports two methods. A slower one is used if it is unable to allocate enough memory. I was looking to re-create this behavior for the C++ version, although I normally don't expect to run out of memory. We already got rid of this type of fall-back on another one of the algorithms used by the program when we found my C++ implementation was much more efficient in terms of memory than the older Java one.

Answer (score 0):

The absence of explicit exception-specification is intentional. See [this](http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Exception-specification) sub-section for an explanation. Further, note that an absence of an explicit specification means that there is no restriction on the type of exception a function can throw. So, at the least, the ctor and the resize function can throw exceptions in case memory is exhausted or if an item-object copy fails.

Some generic references which inspired Boost which you may be interested in are:

- [Exception-Safety in Generic Components](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html)
- [Error and Exception Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html)

Comment: @gimpf: No, but the lack of the same may have confused him.

Comment: May well be.  I hope for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test it ? It's easy to pass an absurdly high value to generate the exception.

On the other hand, what do you plan on doing if does generate this exception ? `std::bad_alloc` is the kind of exception that you usually cannot deal with at micro level...

For example, on a webserver, you would typically perform some cleanup (rollback on db transaction ?) and then return a `500` error to the user.

But when memory is exhausted, there is no much you can do safely, since you have to tread carefully if you don't want to once again hit the memory wall that you know is close :)

Comment: this is a scientific algorithm that can fall back to a less memory intensive (slower) method if the allocation fails.  Basically there are two dynamically allocated 3-dimensional arrays to hold "distances" (correlation) between all pairs of genes in a query and all genes in a cross-validation set for each of a large number of datasets.  The slower method recalculates each distance on the fly as it is needed. This is for a C++ version of an existing Java implementation, which implemented both methods and would fall back on an out of memory exception. I don't really expect to run out of memory

Comment: It is all well-intentioned, but the problem is that in systems like Linux (unless it is configured to do so), the allocations typically never fail (throw); it is only later when the memory is actually used (paged) that the system fails in some way that cannot be detected or recovered from within the program. If you are using other kinds of memory, like memory resources or GPUs, the memory exhaustion can be detected at the point of allocation and not later, but of course, that would be changing the question.

Comment: For reference, @alfC is referring here to overcommit, which is enabled by default on most Linux distributions. Even with overcommit active, memory allocation _can_ fail, for very large allocations. Otherwise, the system will try to find a page (4KB, 2MB, or 1GB being the typical sizes on x64) only on first access, possibly freeing up space from its caches, or roping in the OOM killer.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that other answer touched on this. So, yes, this makes bad_alloc much less useful that what it seems. I wonder if one can do a small trivial operation to trigger a segfault and then detect the segfault it by some (non portable) mechanism.

Comment: @alfC: Catching signals is possible on Linux, at least, though it gets finicky in multi-threaded applications AFAIK, and there's the issue of communicating the answer to the call site (a signal handler has not return) though if encapsulated in the allocation function (just writing a single byte every 4K bytes) then it's possible to (1) set a probing flag before probing and reset a segfault flag, (2) probe, (3) in the signal handler set a segfault flag if the probing flag is set, otherwise forward the signal, (4) reset the probing flag, return NULL if the segfault flag is set...

Comment: ... This is still assuming that the signal handler is executed on the same thread -- otherwise you can't have thread-local flags and it's a mess. It'd be more reliable to disable overcommit at this point.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wonder if there is an example of this precise use online or where this magic size (e.g., 4KB) can be obtained from. As far as I know, overcommitting needs root access to be disabled. So, it is not something that one can do flexibly or per application.

Comment: @alfC: The 4KB would be the page size, you need to write at least 1 byte per page to ensure it's committed. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888067/how-to-get-page-size-programmatically-within-linux-kernel-module-code . 4KB will work on all existing architectures, AFAIK, though it may not be optimal (ie, it may underestimate the page size, leading to more writes than strictly necessary).

Comment: yes, I was wondering about the optimal (in my machine is 4KB BTW). Sounds inefficient, a 4GB allocation will need to make 4 million writes in a loop. Well, allocating is slow anyway.

Comment: @alfC: Actually, a 4GB allocation only has 1 million 4KB pages. At this stage, the OS has hopefully switched to 2MB pages... but it's unclear how you can detect that it did...

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuM., I am interested in this, since I have my own multidimensional array library (https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi) that is used with lots of routines that can benefit from falling back to smaller scratch space if memory is not available (LAPACK), and I am trying to have the option of a true "bad alloc", at least in Linux.