# How to get the pagesize of a memory segment just from a virtual address?

Tags: c, numa

Linux can have both standard 4KiB page memory and 1GiB (huge) paged memory (and 2MiB pages, but I don't know if anyone uses that).

Is there a standard call to get the page size from an arbitrary virtual address? The pointer could be pointing to 4K pages or huge pages.

The problem at hand is to sanity (`assert(...)`) check arguments to a function that requires the base address and size of the region needs to be multiples of the page size, to be handed to `mbind`.  But the page size varies on the system.  Without sanity checking, the return value of `mbind` just gives `Invalid argument` which is not helpful for debugging.

I've looked at this answer [How to get linux kernel page size programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888067/how-to-get-linux-kernel-page-size-programmatically) but it gives answers that assume that the entire system is the same, and they are also compile time constants.  Also `getpagesize()` does the same and it is deprecated anyways.

Comment: I think this is a tad more complicated. The default configuration involves transparent huge pages, which means that userspace thinks everything is 4k and there is `khugepaged` that chugs away in the background and converts consecutive chunks into 2M huge pages. Almost the only programs that request huge pages explicitely are VMs like qemu/kvm... So is it the explicit huge pages you are running into or the randomly created transparent ones?

Comment: The transparent ones can be disabled for the whole system or using `madvise` for a specific memory region.

Comment: IMHO for a user process there is only one pagesize, and that is what sysconf reports.

Comment: I have written a program where huge pages are explicitly mapped using mmap or shmget/shmat, and it is definitely mixed 4K and 1G pages.  I'm not using transparent huge pages.  I realize for my application, I "know" which pointers are huge and which aren't, but I want to protect my library.

Comment: @dratenik these are explicit huge maps. I have used mmap and shmget/shmat to allocate the huge pages.  Now I need to add NUMA binding to the mix.

Comment: If you're the one doing the allocations, maybe hugetlbfs+mmap would be easier to decode in /proc/xx/maps as the page size is part of the mount options and if you have multiple sizes, you would have multiple mount points.

Comment: so given a virtual address of your program, you want to know if it is mapped to 4K physical frame or a huge one?

Comment: @blaze9 I want to know the size of the page, be it 4K, 2M or 1G, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the MMU, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128213/how-is-page-size-determined-in-virtual-address-space and normally the page size is equal for the entire system / kernel, it is determined during kernel compilation

Comment: Normally that is true, but I am writing an application that uses huge pages, allocated from XSI shared memory.  And in the past I've used huge pages from mmap.  The page size is not equal for the application.  We have a big data buffer that uses 100-1000 GiB of RAM and interfaces with hardware that requires huge pages.

Answer (score 0):

I realize one way of doing it is to scrape `/proc/self/maps` and somewhere in there is a keyword that indicates if a memory range has huge pages or not.  I don't know how portable that is (man page for /proc doesn't say what it is, but I've seen it).  But that seems a heavy handed way of just looking up a pointer to get the page size.  And then on top of that, I don't think it indicates page size, just whether or not it is "huge pages".

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% i understand your requirements correctly, but i 'll give it a try.

There is an interesting function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748492/is-there-any-api-for-determining-the-physical-address-from-virtual-address-in-li/45128487#45128487) by user [Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli%E6%96%B0%E7%96%86%E6%A3%89%E8%8A%B1trump-ban-bad), `pagemap_get_entry`. It uses the /proc/[pid]/pagemap interface to get the page table entry (pte) that corresponds to the virtual address you give as input. From the pte, you get the pfn (physical frame number) where the virtual address is mapped. Having this function, we can use the following logic to find out if a virtual address is mapped to 4K, 2M or 1G physical page:

First, get the address of the 1G *virtual* page where the virtual address of interest belongs. Call pagemap_get_entry with that virtual address and if the returned pfn is 2<sup>18</sup>-aligned, then assume we are on a 1G physical page (2<sup>18</sup> is used because we assume size of physical frame to be  4K=2<sup>12</sup> bytes and 2<sup>18</sup>*2<sup>12</sup>=2<sup>30</sup>=1GiB).

Else, get the address of the 2M *virtual* page inside which the virtual address falls. Call pagemap_get_entry with that and if the returned pfn is 2<sup>9</sup>-aligned, then assume we are inside a 2M physical page (again 2<sup>9</sup>*2<sup>12</sup>=2<sup>21</sup>=2MiB).

Else, assume that virtual address is mapped in RAM with 4K physical page.

With code, i hope it would be something like that (part of linked post is reposted here for completeness):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <fcntl.h> /* open */
#include <stdint.h> /* uint64_t  */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* size_t, malloc */
#include <unistd.h> /* pread, sysconf, getpid */
#include <sys/types.h> /* getpid */
#include <string.h> /* memset */

typedef struct {
    uint64_t pfn : 55;
    unsigned int soft_dirty : 1;
    unsigned int file_page : 1;
    unsigned int swapped : 1;
    unsigned int present : 1;
} PagemapEntry;

/* Parse the pagemap entry for the given virtual address.
 *
 * @param[out] entry      the parsed entry
 * @param[in]  pagemap_fd file descriptor to an open /proc/pid/pagemap file
 * @param[in]  vaddr      virtual address to get entry for
 * @return 0 for success, 1 for failure
 */
int pagemap_get_entry(PagemapEntry *entry, int pagemap_fd, uintptr_t vaddr)
{
    size_t nread;
    ssize_t ret;
    uint64_t data;
    uintptr_t vpn;

    vpn = vaddr / sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    nread = 0;
    while (nread < sizeof(data)) {
        ret = pread(pagemap_fd, ((uint8_t*)&data) + nread, sizeof(data) - nread,
                vpn * sizeof(data) + nread);
        nread += ret;
        if (ret <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    entry->pfn = data & (((uint64_t)1 << 55) - 1);
    entry->soft_dirty = (data >> 55) & 1;
    entry->file_page = (data >> 61) & 1;
    entry->swapped = (data >> 62) & 1;
    entry->present = (data >> 63) & 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_1G = 1024*1024*1024;
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_2M = 2*1024*1024;
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_4K = 4*1024;
   uint64_t pfn_1g, pfn_2m, pfn_4k, pfn_original;

   char * arr = (char *)malloc(4*PAGE_SIZE_1G * sizeof(char));
   if (arr == NULL) {
      printf("malloc\n");
      return 1;
   }
   memset(arr, 1, 4*PAGE_SIZE_1G);
   uintptr_t vaddr = (uintptr_t)arr + 1024*1025*1026; // get a random virtual address
   PagemapEntry entry;

   uintptr_t vaddr_1g_aligned = vaddr & ~(PAGE_SIZE_1G - 1);
   uintptr_t vaddr_2m_aligned = vaddr & ~(PAGE_SIZE_2M - 1);
   uintptr_t vaddr_4k_aligned = vaddr & ~(PAGE_SIZE_4K - 1);

   printf("Virtual address of interest %jx\n", (uintmax_t) vaddr);
   printf("1G-aligned virtual address  %jx\n", (uintmax_t) vaddr_1g_aligned);
   printf("2M-aligned virtual address  %jx\n", (uintmax_t) vaddr_2m_aligned);
   printf("4K-aligned virtual address  %jx\n", (uintmax_t) vaddr_4k_aligned);

   char pagemap_file[BUFSIZ];
   int pagemap_fd;
   pid_t pid = getpid();

   snprintf(pagemap_file, sizeof(pagemap_file), "/proc/%ju/pagemap", (uintmax_t)pid);
   pagemap_fd = open(pagemap_file, O_RDONLY);
   if (pagemap_fd < 0) {
       return 1;
   }

   if (pagemap_get_entry(&entry, pagemap_fd, vaddr_1g_aligned)) {
      printf("pagemap_get_entry\n");
      return 1;
   }
   pfn_1g = entry.pfn;
   if (pagemap_get_entry(&entry, pagemap_fd, vaddr_2m_aligned)) {
      printf("pagemap_get_entry\n");
      return 1;   
   }
   pfn_2m = entry.pfn;
   if (pagemap_get_entry(&entry, pagemap_fd, vaddr_4k_aligned)) {
      printf("pagemap_get_entry\n");
      return 1;   
   }
   pfn_4k = entry.pfn;
   if (pagemap_get_entry(&entry, pagemap_fd, vaddr)) {
      printf("pagemap_get_entry\n");
      return 1;   
   }
   pfn_original = entry.pfn;

   printf("pfn of 1G-alignment:     %jx\n", (uintmax_t) pfn_1g);
   printf("pfn of 2M-alignment:     %jx\n", (uintmax_t) pfn_2m);
   printf("pfn of 4K-alignment:     %jx\n", (uintmax_t) pfn_4k);
   printf("pfn of original address: %jx\n", (uintmax_t) pfn_original);

   if ((pfn_1g != 0) && (pfn_1g % (1 << 18) == 0)) {
      printf("Virtual address is mapped to 1G physical page\n");
   }
   else if ((pfn_2m != 0) && (pfn_2m % (1 << 9) == 0)) {
      printf("Virtual address is mapped to 2M physical page\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("Virtual address is mapped to 4K physical page\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

As original poster [explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345915/how-to-change-permission-of-proc-self-pagemap-file/383838#383838), you have to run this program with sudo, because of read access to /proc/<pid>/pagemap.

In my system that supports only 2M and 4K page sizes, i get the followings:

```
root@debian # cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepages/enabled
always madvise [never]
root@debian # ./physical_page_size
Virtual address of interest 7f4f9d01a810
1G-aligned virtual address  7f4f80000000
2M-aligned virtual address  7f4f9d000000
4K-aligned virtual address  7f4f9d01a000
pfn of 1G-alignment:     1809fa
pfn of 2M-alignment:     1639fa
pfn of 4K-alignment:     163a14
pfn of original address: 163a14
Virtual address is mapped to 4K physical page
root@debian # echo "always" > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepages/enabled
root@debian # ./physical_page_size
Virtual address of interest 7f978d0d2810
1G-aligned virtual address  7f9780000000
2M-aligned virtual address  7f978d000000
4K-aligned virtual address  7f978d0d2000
pfn of 1G-alignment:     137a00
pfn of 2M-alignment:     145a00
pfn of 4K-alignment:     145ad2
pfn of original address: 145ad2
Virtual address is mapped to 2M physical page
```

Also, i have to mention that when the program reports 1G or 2M physical page size, it is not guaranteed that this is the case, however is very highly possible.

Finally, i see that your problem is with mbind. Again, i am not sure i understand it correctly or if this is a valid suggestion, but maybe you could try all possible page sizes starting from smallest until the call succeeds.

```
int wrapper(void *start, unsigned long size)
{
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_4K = 4*1024;
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_2M = 2*1024*1024;
   unsigned long long PAGE_SIZE_1G = 1024*1024*1024;

   void *start_4k = (void *)((unsigned long) start & ~(PAGE_SIZE_4K-1));
   void *start_2m = (void *)((unsigned long) start & ~(PAGE_SIZE_2M-1));
   void *start_1g = (void *)((unsigned long) start & ~(PAGE_SIZE_1G-1));
   unsigned long size_4k, size_2m, size_1g;
   if (size % PAGE_SIZE_4K != 0) {
      size_4k = size - (size % PAGE_SIZE_4K) + PAGE_SIZE_4K;
   }
   if (size % PAGE_SIZE_2M != 0) {
      size_2m = size - (size % PAGE_SIZE_2M) + PAGE_SIZE_2M;
   }
   if (size % PAGE_SIZE_1G != 0) {
      size_1g = size - (size % PAGE_SIZE_1G) + PAGE_SIZE_1G;
   }

   if (mbind(start_4k, size_4k, .....) == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   if (mbind(start_2m, size_2m, .....) == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   if (mbind(start_1g, size_1g, .....) == 0) {
      return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}
```